# How can I execute a PostgreSQL function with Spring`s JDBCTemplate?

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I created a custom PostgreSQL function:

```
create function delete_classes() returns void as
$$
    DELETE FROM ...;
$$ language sql;
```

I would like to call this function with Spring`s JDBCTemplate. I tried the following:

```
@Repository
class Repository {
    private final JdbcTemplate template; // initialized in constructor

    public void deleteClasses() {
        template.update("select delete_classes()");
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select delete_classes()];
A result was returned when none was expected.;
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:
A result was returned when none was expected.
```

The PostgreSQL function `delete_classes` returns `void`, so I am not really sure what is meant here. The `DELETE` statement has no `RETURNING ...` clause.

What is the correct way to execute the function?

**update**

I tried the following (`execute` instead of `update`):

```
@Repository
class Repository {
    private final JdbcTemplate template; // initialized in constructor

    public void deleteClasses() {
        template.execute("select delete_classes()", statement -> null);
    }
}
```

Here, this implements a `PreparedStatementCallback` in lambda-fashion which just returns null.

The function `delete_classes` is not called now.

Comment: Don't use `update()` use `execute()`

Comment: I tried that, but I am not really sure how to implement the `PreparedStatementCallback` callback, as I don't need any results. See update of question.